# wp_editor adds HTML entities to the content

Tags: html, wp-editor

I'm building my theme options page and I want to use Wordpress TinyMCE editor here, so I'm calling `wp_editor`. But when I'm saving data some entities are added to the content for example, lets say I want to add image:

`<img class="" title="" src="path_to_image" alt="" />`

Thats what I've got after clicking save:

`<img title="\&quot;\&quot;" src="\&quot;path_to_image\&quot;" alt="\&quot;\&quot;" />`

Why is this changing quotes into entities (and leaves actual - correctly displayed quotes?)??

@edit:
This is how I display my editor:

```
    $class = (isset($value['class'])) ? $value['class']:'';
    $content = (get_option($value['id']) ? get_option($value['id']) : '');

    $settings = array(
        'textarea_name' => $value['id'], 
        'editor_class' => $class
        );
    wp_editor($content, strtolower($value['id']), $settings );
```

And that's how I save data for this field:

```
update_option($value['id'],
$_POST[ $value['id'] ]);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WordPress is running `addslashes` on `POST` input. The value you get from the data base looks probably like:

```
<img title=\"\" …
```

… and the editor tries to enforce valid markup from that.

So … call the editor with …

```
wp_editor( stripslashes( $content ), strtolower($value['id']), $settings );
```

Answer (score 4):

I too had same problem.
Then I used :

`<? wp_editor(html_entity_decode(stripcslashes(get_option('wid1_cont'))), "editor1",$settings = array('textarea_name'=>'wid1_cont','textarea_rows'=>'5') ); ?>`

It worked..

Comment: Please explain your solution. Why is it better than the other approaches?

Comment: @Pavan I know they say not to comment Thank you but - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, the problem not is in save: is just on view stage.

Try:

```
 wp_editor( html_entity_decode($content), strtolower($value['id']), $settings );
```